# MySQL do I need to lock tables?

Tags: mysql, locking

I need to create a tiny reservation system for a teacher. There are a number of project topics which he intends to put online at a certain time and students will be able to choose one topic each.

Let us suppose there is a table with two columns 'topic' and 'name_of_student'. I am going to assign student names to topics using UPDATE, but would like to avoid a situation where two people book the same topic at the same time.

Should I worry about that or does mysql prevents that? Or should I explicitly use some kind of a locking mechanism and if yes what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two students access the database from different places, you cannot just `UPDATE` the table because you may overwrite the first person's reservation.

A common strategy in this case is to add a `WHERE` clause to check that the topic is still available at the time you are making it final, e.g. instead of

```
UPDATE topics SET name_of_student = 'Bonzoq' WHERE topic_id = 1
```

you would write

```
UPDATE topics SET name_of_student = 'Bonzoq' WHERE topic_id = 1 
    AND name_of_student IS NULL
```

and check that the number of affected records is equal to 1. If it is equal to 0, then the `UPDATE` failed because the `name_of_student` is not `NULL` anymore.